# Why do glob.glob and pathlib.Path.glob treat hidden files differently?

Tags: python, glob, hidden-files

Consider this folder containing two files:

```
test/
    foo
    .bar
```

Calling [`glob.glob('*')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) on this folder won't list the hidden `.bar` file:

```
>>> glob.glob('test/*')
['test/foo']
```

But [`pathlib.Path.glob('*')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) will:

```
>>> list(Path('test').glob('*'))
[PosixPath('test/.bar'), PosixPath('test/foo')]
```

I'd like to know if this is intended or possibly a bug/oversight.

---

The [`glob` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) states that files starting with a dot are special cased:

> glob treats filenames beginning with a dot (.) as special cases

Meaning that the result given by `glob.glob('*')` is intended. But what about pathlib's `glob`? I couldn't find any relevant information in the docs. Is this the intended behavior? Shouldn't both functions produce the same results?

Comment: The discussion there explains well why dotfiles are returned, but not the inconsistency with glob.glob() - you ca put that down to history.

Comment: @vaultah Oh, nice find. Could I convince you to post that as an answer so you can take my upvote?

Comment: You sure aren't easily bribed. What if I throw in a green check mark next to your answer? :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [issue #26096](https://bugs.python.org/issue26096) on the official bug tracker, this difference has been deemed `not a bug` and is therefore completely intended.

Credits to [@vaultah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/vaultah) for the find.