# Disparity between PurePath.match(pattern) and Path.glob(pattern)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

If [PurePath.match(pattern)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.match) does

> Match this path against the provided glob-style pattern. Return True if matching is successful, False otherwise

and [Path.glob(pattern)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) will

> Glob the given pattern in the directory represented by this path, yielding all matching files (of any kind):

### Question-1

Then why the below assertion fails?

```
query_files = Path('../').glob("sql-queries/**/*.sql")
filtered_files = [fname for fname in query_files if fname.match("sql-queries/**/*.sql")]
assert query_files == filtered_files # This assertion fails?
```

### Question-2

How can we modify the `PurePath.match` pattern, to ensure the assertion does not fail.

**NB** The recursive pattern fails to `Path.match` the files under base path which are matched and returned by `Path.glob`. This seems to be the observable discrepancies between the two APIs.

### QnA

**Q:** Can you give an example of a specific path that appears in query_files but not filtered_files?

**A:**

```
query_files = <class 'list'>: [
                    PosixPath('../sql-queries/combined_gv.sql'), 
                    PosixPath('../sql-queries/gv_with_merchant.sql'), 
                    PosixPath('../sql-queries/merchant_dimension.sql'), 
                    PosixPath('../sql-queries/gen_test_data/combined_gv.sql'),
                    PosixPath('../sql-queries/gen_test_data/merchant_dimension.sql')]
filtered_files = <class 'list'>: [
                    PosixPath('../sql-queries/gen_test_data/combined_gv.sql'),
                    PosixPath('../sql-queries/gen_test_data/merchant_dimension.sql')]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific path that appears in `query_files` but not `filtered_files`?

Comment: @user2357112: See my edit. Have answered your comment with an example

Comment: @user2357112 Note that `Path.glob('*')` includes dot-prefixed paths, like `.hidden.txt`, unlike `glob.glob`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862648/why-do-glob-glob-and-pathlib-path-glob-treat-hidden-files-differently and [Python issue 26096](https://bugs.python.org/issue26096) (which was deemed a feature by GvR); that may have to do with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path.glob` and `Path.match` are backed by different glob implementations with different behavior. Particularly, `Path.match` doesn't support `**`.

It's weird and inconsistent and probably not originally intended, but I don't know if they'll change it.